# Aggregate/Summarize Timeseries data in Azure Data Explorer using Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a requirement where I need to regularize/aggregate data which is polled every 1 sec into 1 min intervals. And I have two columns which need to be aggregated as well, say SensorName, SensorValue. I am able to bin the timestamp to 1 minute, but I am not able to get the corresponding two colums. How do I do that? Below is the query I used and the output I get.

```
Table
| where TimeStamp between (datetime(2020-09-01)..datetime(2020-09-30))
| summarize by bin(TimeStamp , 1min)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

based on my understanding of the question (could be wrong, as there's no clear specification of sample input/schema and matching output), you could try following this example - it calculates the average sensor value for each sensor name, using an aggregation span of 1 minute:

```
Table
| where TimeStamp between (datetime(2020-09-01)..datetime(2020-09-30))
| summarize avg(SensorValue) by SensorName, bin(TimeStamp, 1min)
```

Comment: Thanks Yoni. I think it works. But some of the values in the SensorValue are boolean, like True and False. Will the avg() condition work?

Comment: The function 'avg()' is not compatible with arguments(dynamic) --I get this message

Comment: as mentioned in the answer, it's just an example. you should choose the aggregation function based on your needs. you can extend/cast to a strongly-typed column based on a property in a dynamic one. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#casting-dynamic-objects

Comment: Thanks Yoni. Will update the answer with the modified query, once I figure out the issue.

Comment: I was able to get the result I need by using the cast.Table
| where TimeStamp between (datetime(2020-09-01)..datetime(2020-09-30))
| summarize avg(tolong(SensorValue)) by SensorName, bin(TimeStamp , 1min)